# Dialogflow Entity Match Issues

Tags: dialogflow-es

We built an intent to detect user's last four digits of social security numbers. The training phrases capture @sys.number-sequence and @sys.number entities. We match the intent using voice (audio). When the digits are read out separately, @sys.number-sequence is matched. When we say forty five sixty seven (4567) or four thousand five hundred and sixty seven (4567), @sys.number is match. This works fine for most of the numbers. But we ran into the following two issues:

1. When we read "one one one one", none of the two entities is matched. The voice is actually transcribed as "one one one one". But it is not matched to a number sequence of 1111.
2. When we say "eighty two seventy five", @sys.number is matched, but only 82 is captured. The parameter value is 82 as opposed to 8275.

Appreciate it if someone could shed some light on these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this could also be the issue of Speech to Text engine that you are using. But to check the Dialogflow, I built following Entity and Intent and I was able to capture 4 digits easily. 
I tested using Dialogflow's Mic option for voice commands.

Also, check out the other [systems entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities) that you may use to capture numbers even though they are designed for something else like zipcode.

Hope the following example helps.
**Entity**
[image]

**Intent**
[image]

Comment: This entity does help in more reliably identifying four digits. Thanks.